# How to implant a bot framework bot into an existing mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, botframework

Thank you for visiting my problem.
As you know from the title, I want to know how to add bot to the already existing mvc.
And I'm going to host it locally with iis.
In general, chatbots are located in the lower right corner of the screen.
Then I want a bot that is actually operated on web, not a bot that is viewed as an emulator.
I wonder if the bot framework implements a button at the bottom right with a separate css or image when the bot is actually implanted.
Can you help me solve this problem?

[bot app and web app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqpkV.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is probably helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090353/how-to-add-my-ms-bot-app-in-my-own-asp-net-web-application

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this tutorial as it looks like what you are searching to do :

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/871501/Adding-a-Self-Hosted-Chatbot-to-an-ASP-NET-Website

Regards

Comment: The question is about the Microsoft Bot Framework (#botframework tagged) but this article is not.